# How to combine string args in launch file?

Tags: roslaunch, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is my starting .launch file

```
  <launch>
<!-- usb webcam video0 -->
  <node name="usb_cam0" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0" />
  </node>
 </launch>
```

Now I would like to pass that zero as an argument by a command like

```
roslaunch mypackage mylauncher.launch N:=0
```

so I thought

```
  <launch>
<arg name="N"/>
<!-- usb webcam video number N as indicated in the argument -->
  <node name="usb_cam0" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
   <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video$(arg N)" />
  </node>
 </launch>
```

Of course it does not work. I'm not an axpert at all of xml-like files... maybe the error is the combination of the string?
Or there is a way to do this better?

My final purpose is to allow the access to any video source with inputs in the launchfile

```
dev/video0
dev/video1
dev/video2
```

etc.

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267043/how-to-combine-string-args-in-launch-file?/) by [marcoresk](https://answers.ros.org/users/28398/marcoresk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2017-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Of course it does not work

can you tell us what you see, if it does not work?

This:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="n" />
  <param name="something" value="/dev/video$(arg n)"/>
</launch>
```

started as `roslaunch my_pkg test.launch n:=4` result in:

```
something: /dev/video4
```

on my system.

See [wiki/roslaunch/XML/arg](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg) and [wiki/roslaunch/XML/param](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcoresk](https://answers.ros.org/users/28398/marcoresk/) on 2017-09-01**:
I tried again after some time, now it works. Thank you for the proof.